# Закрытие контактной формы после отправки сообщения

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть контактная форма для отправки сообщений на мыло, которая всплывает по клику из меню. Хотелось, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "отправить" после показа окна об успешной доставке она закрывалась сама. Помогите, у кого время есть. )

```
<div id="envelope" class="envelope">

<form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
Как к Вам обращаться:
<input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="фамилия имя отчество" x-autocompletetype="name">
Email для связи:
<input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="адрес электронной почты" x-autocompletetype="email">
Ваше сообщение:
<textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="отправить" onclick="closeWindow()">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('feedback-form').onsubmit = function(){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.send("nameFF=" + this.nameFF.value + "&contactFF=" + this.contactFF.value + "&messageFF=" + this.messageFF.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

      alert(http.responseText + ', Ваше сообщение получено.\nНаши специалисты ответят Вам в течении 2-х дней.\nБлагодарим за интерес к нашей фирме!');

    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
  return false;
}

</script>

         </div>
```

Comment: @mad_rover, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[window.close](http://javascript.ru/window.close)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, после

`alert(http.responseText + ', Ваше сообщение получено.\nНаши специалисты ответят Вам в течении 2-х дней.\nБлагодарим за интерес к нашей фирме!');`

добавить

`$('#envelope').fadeOut(300);`